# What does "kick the long ball" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the phrase 'kick the long ball' mean in the lines below?

> Real maturity begins when you finally realize that no-one is coming to the rescue.  It is only when you accept total responsibility for your life situation, with no excuses & no blaming of others, that you move into a mental position to 'kick the long ball' in your own life.

Answer (score 2):

In European football, [long ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_ball) is to

> attempt to move the ball a long distance down the field via a cross, without the intention to pass it to the feet of the receiving player

The metaphor (on the field or in life overall) is to attempt a somewhat risky play, such that if you're either lucky or good at what you're doing, you can capitalize on to significantly improve your position.

Comment: Teams must use the "long ball" when time is running out and they are behind, when there is not time for a safer but slower approach. It is a "do or die" approach which may tie in with the first part of the quote "Real maturity begins when you finally ..."